# Find amount of pairs of (x,y) where x^k + y^k = n

Tags: algorithm, math, number-theory

Recently I saw number theory problem in which I need to find amount of pairs (x,y) that gives the solution for x^k + y^k = n, where k and n is given. The only solution I came with is the bruteforce all possible pairs of x,y and check if they equal to n. But I need to do it for big n and k, 1 <= n <= 10^18, 1<=k<=100.
What is the most efficient way to do it ?

Comment: Many possible optimizations, but the first one: there's no need to brute force the *pairs*. For each candidate `x`, find `n - x^k` and figure out whether it's a kth power or not. (You'll want to special-case `k=1`, of course, and there are number-theoretic tricks available for `k=2`, too.)

Comment: Shall `x` and `y` be *positive*?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yes, x and y are natural numbers

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93316/integer-solutions-to-x2y2-n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach would be to use [a hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

First, compute all values x<sup>k</sup>, for which the result is below n. Add each such value into a hash table, mapping x<sup>k</sup> -> x (and not the other way around, it will be clear in a moment why).

Afterwards, iterate through the keys x<sup>k</sup> from the hash set, and check whether the complement, *i.e.* n - x<sup>k</sup> is also a key in the hash set.

If n - x<sup>k</sup> is also a key, then the hash table would map it into the value y, such that n - x<sup>k</sup> = y<sup>k</sup>, and we identified a valid (x, y) pair.

Otherwise, if n - x<sup>k</sup> is not a key of the hash table, then there is no solution where x is one element.

---

There are improvements to the base idea above. For example, if a good pair (x, y) is found, then this means (y, x) is also a good pair. Using this, one could not test for x values above n/2, since this would result in pairs already enumerated.

---

EDIT

As Dmitry Bychenko noted in the comments section, there are situations where this approach uses a lot of memory, making it less feasible.

This issue is most evident for k = 2, because as k increases, there are significantly fewer x values for which x<sup>k</sup> < n.

For k = 2, the problem can be approached without using the hash table, but instead directly checking whether n - x<sup>2</sup> is a perfect square. To check if a number is a perfect square, one can apply the sqrt function and check whether the result is an integer value.

---

Another approach, with O(1) space complexity for any k, is to use binary search for checking whether n - x<sup>k</sup> is the k'th power of an integer. This has a time complexity in the class O(n<sup>1/k</sup> * log(n))

Comment: if `n <= 10^18` and `k == 2` then we have to compute as many as *billion* items...